# Formatting court document with vertical banner

Tags: multicolumn

I am trying to recreate this court document that is a word doc, in latex.

[image]

I am having trouble trying to get a vertical column to appear in the left, the same way it does in the word doc. It needs to run through every page. I tried using multi columns,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
[
\columnwidth=0.2\textwidth % set the width of the left column to 0.2 times the width of the text
]
text here
\bigskip

text two

\columnbreak % switch to the next column

\lipsum
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

but I can't seem to get the horizontal sizing correct.

[image]

I would appreciate some help in my quest. Thank you

Comment: These are more like margin notes! Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, that is the correct wording I think!

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  I see two possibilities that might be tried: (1) a wide left margin and margin notes; (2) a wide left margin with the left column contents placed with `\llap` of that width, content flushed left (space filled on the right) using a `\parbox[t]` if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easy to understand example for the margin notes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  left=5cm,
  marginparwidth=3cm,
  marginparsep=1cm,
  ]{geometry}

\usepackage{marginnote}
\reversemarginpar
\renewcommand*{\raggedleftmarginnote}{}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\marginnote{Text text text text text text text}
\lipsum[1]
\marginnote{Text text text text text text text}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I build on hair-splitter's idea, to show you possibilities of LaTeX, as well as differences to a wordprocessor like Word. You will see, that perhaps your requirements will or have to change here and there. Here are the basic ideas.

### Layout

To overwrite the standard-layout use package `geometry`, as was already shown. It introduces a left margin (as well as all others), which you can fill with marginnotes (as was already shown).

### Text variables

Your document literally "asks" for such variables. You can use the `\newcommand` to create macros for this purpose. Here they all accept 0 parameters, as you set their values in the preamble.

In the documents content you just call them like `\sher{}` to insert sheriff's information. This allows for more uniformity, as you change content (and perhaps formatting) in one place only, inside the macros.

### Inside the document

I introduced `\parindent 0pt`, as your copy doesn't indent the first line of a paragraph. I also introduced `\raggedright` for the whole document, which your copy suggests.

Now, remember we are mimicking type-setting. E.g. to introduce an empty line in the days of Gutenberg people inserted a line of lead (a spacer) with no letters on it. Here you can use `\bigskip` (or `\vspace{}` if you need other distances).

In some places a `\\` works to "put" a carriage-return. I used it to clean up the code a little. Else you need to enter a new line in the editor.

You can also see the various places where the "text-variables" are inserted.

The `\marginnote{}` works, more or less (wrt. formatting). HERE might be something you want to review:

- you can, like with Word, enter a lot of text, which the user can delete
- in LaTeX you have perhaps better options via providing more macros
- or, and this might be the most elegant way to do it, you just `\input{}` files, where each one conntains a `* Defender ...` paragraph (not shown here).

The `\lipsum` text I put to show that the layout won't change. I could have checked `\marginnote{}` on page 2, but ... perhaps you no longer need it, see above.

### Preamble

Typically this part grows. I put package `babel` there. You may not need it, but people writing such templates in other languages might do.

That's it, more or less.

[image: example]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% ~~~ layout ~~~~~~~~~~~~
\usepackage[
  left=5cm,
  marginparwidth=3cm,
  marginparsep=1cm,
  ]{geometry}

% ~~~ handling margin notes ~~~~~~~~~~~
\usepackage{marginnote}
\reversemarginpar
\renewcommand*{\raggedleftmarginnote}{}

% ~~~ language specific hyphenation ~~~~
\usepackage{babel}

% ~~~ some text for texts sake ~~~~~~~
\usepackage{lipsum}

% - - - abbreviations ~~~ CHANGE HERE ~~~~
%     individuals, institutions
\newcommand\shat[0]{Paloma County}
\newcommand\sher[0]{sheriffdom}

\newcommand\AB[0]{Sheldon Cooper, Texas}
\newcommand\CD[0]{Will Weaton, Los Angeles}
\newcommand\EF[0]{Judge Willson}

%     what it's all about
\newcommand\summ[0]{\textsterling{}1.000}
\newcommand\circum[0]{attaching an unrespectful note to the front door}


% ~~~ and now: the content ~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}

\parindent 0pt  % you don't want the fist line indented
\raggedright    % if you want the whole document that way

\marginnote{Form 010}
\textbf{Form of third party notice}
\bigskip

\marginnote{Rule 20.1}
Court ref.no.
\bigskip

SHERIFFDOM OF \sher{}\\
AT \shat{}
\bigskip

THIRD PARTY NOTICE

in the cause\\
\AB{}, Pursuer

against\\
\CD{}, Defender
\bigskip

To \EF{}

You are given notice by \CD{} of an order granted by Sheriff NAME in this action in which \AB{} is the pursuer and \CD{} the defender. In the action the pursuer claims against the defender the sum of \summ{} damages in respect of \circum{}.

\marginnote{* Delete as appropriate}
* The defender admits (or denies) liability jadajadajada jadajadajada jadajadajada jadajadajada jadajadajada jadajadajada

* The defender denies liabilty for jadajadajada jadajadajada jadajadajada jadajadajada jadajadajada 

\lipsum[1-3]


\end{document}
```

**P.S.**: This one "cures" the formatting of the Delete margin:

```
\marginnote{\raggedright * Delete as appropriate}
* The defender
```

[image: proof]